# How can I prove this relation (combinatorics)

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-theorem, inclusion-exclusion

How can I prove this relation?

${ a }_{ n }=\sum _{ k=0 }^{ n }{ { (-1) }^{ k }\left( \begin{matrix} n \\ k \end{matrix} \right) { b }_{ k } } \quad$ if and only if    $\quad{ b }_{ n }=\sum _{ k=0 }^{ n }{ { (-1) }^{ k }\left( \begin{matrix} n \\ k \end{matrix} \right) a_{ k } } $

I think I have to consider a combinatoric proof... but I can't go any further...
So, I searched about this topic, and can find some documents related to "binomial inverse pairs". But still I can't solve it.

Comment: do you mean ${ a }_{ n }=\sum _{ k=0 }^{ n }{ { (-1) }^{ k }\left( \begin{matrix} n \\ k \end{matrix} \right) b _{k} }$?

Comment: Thanks. You're right. I edit it.

Answer (score 3):

To prove the corrected formula, put $\displaystyle f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{a_n}{n!}x^n$ and $\displaystyle g(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{b_n}{n!}x^n$; then the first relation say that $f(-x)=\exp(-x)g(x)$, it is easy to finish.

Comment: thanks. i have a hint. but what about this relation f(x)=exp(-x)g(x)...? Is not it right to do this?

Comment: You have the same relation between the $a_n$ and the $b_n$. So the functional relation between $f$ and $g$ must be symmetric. This is the case for $f(-x)=\exp(-x)g(x)$ (replace $x$ by $-x$ to prove $g(-x)=\exp(-x)f(x)$) but not for $f(x)=\exp(-x)g(x)$.

Comment: Oh I see. I have a mistake. Thank you:)